# How to move specific cells in an excel file to a new column with openpyxl in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, move

I am trying to moving some specific cells to a designated location. As shown in the image, would like to move data in cells D3 to E2, D5 to E4,..... so on so for. Is it doable with openpyxl? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciate it!!
[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUjwX.png)

Here is what I got so far. It worked per say.

```
wb=xl.load_workbook(datafile)
ws=wb['Sheet1']

#insert a new column #5
ws.insert_cols(idx=5,amount=1)
wb.save(datafile)

mr=ws.max_row
   
#move cells

for i in range (1,mr+1):
    v=ws.cell(row = i+1,column=4) 
    ws.cell(row=i,column =5).value=v.value

wb.save(datafile)
wb.close
```

Thanks for the help.

I revised the codes and it worked well. I then wanted to delete the unwanted rows and it didn't work. Looks like it got into an infinite loop. Codes are shown here. What did I do wrong?

```
wb=xl.load_workbook(datafile)
ws=wb['Sheet1']
#insert a new column #5
ws.insert_cols(idx=5,amount=1)

#Calculate total number of rows 
mr=ws.max_row
   
#move cells
for i in range (2,mr,2):
    ws.cell(row=i,column=5).value=ws.cell(row=i+1,column=4).value

#delete unwanted rows
for i in range (2,mr,2):
    ws.delete_rows(idx=i+1,amount=1)
    
wb.save(datafile)
```

Comment: Sure, it's doable. What have you tried yourself? Please share your code and explain what problems you encountered or specifically what issue you can't resolve. Have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask).

Comment: I don't have any codes yet. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: You start by creating a `.py` file, adding `import openpyxl` and having a look at some examples online of how to write code using OpenPyXL. Have a look at [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask). "How to solve this problem with code" is not [on topic for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: You can look at this tutorial for the basic idea, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-how-to-copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another/?ref=gcse. Of course in your case you are copying within the same sheet so only need the one workbook and worksheet object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a good effort.
Here are some comments to help and also on how to skip one row.

1. Should generally only ever need to save the workbook once at the end of all your edits, unless you are making multiple copies. So the wb.save after the insert command is not necessary.
2. There shouldn't be need to use 'mr + 1' here. Just the value 'mr' is fine, it matches the rows count.
3. Not necessary to assign an intermediate variable for just copying a value from one cell to another. Assign the new cell value to the existing cell value in one line as shown. However it's fine if you want to use the variable 'v' as an intermediate.
4. wb.close should be wb.close() however wont do anything on this workbook anyway *Only affects read-only and write-only modes* which is a method when opening the workbook. So not need to include that line.

To skip rows you can set the stepping in the range. Stepping is the last number in the range params. So

```
range(2, mr, 2)
```

Means 'i' starts at 2, increases to max value [ws.max_row] in increments of 2.
In this case since the max value is 7, i will be 2, 4 and 6

...

```
wb = xl.load_workbook(datafile)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

# insert a new column #5
ws.insert_cols(idx=5, amount=1)
# wb.save(datafile)  # <--- not necessary just save at the end

mr = ws.max_row

# move cells
# Move and delete the rows by making the changes from the bottom up
for i in reversed(range(2,mr,2)):
    ws.cell(row=i, column=5).value = ws.cell(row=i + 1, column=4).value
    ws.delete_rows(idx=i + 1, amount=1)

wb.save(datafile)
# wb.close  # <-- Not needed, should have brackets anyway
```

#---- Additional Information ----#
The issue with the deletion is; when you delete a row the rows below shift up immediately. Therefore if you delete row 2 then row 3 becomes row 2 which means starting from the top and deleting down in a pattern like this usually wont work.
To delete the unncessary rows its easier to run the loop in reverse so  deletion of a row doesn't affect the rows you have yet to change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I revised the codes and had a new problem. Could you take a look at the codes above and advise? Appreciate it!!

Comment: @Michael Jiang Just a couple of things. I notice you have set your range to **(1,mr,2)** and so are now copying D2, D4 and D6 not the D3 to E2, D5 to E4... as indicated in the question. D2 is copied to the Header row E1, is this what you want now? Since **(2,mr,2)** range matches the original copy spec I'll leave it as that and have updated the code to include deletion of the row the values are copied from. This is achieved in the same loop as the copy and we a reversing the loop, starting from the bottom and working up due to how deletion works, see additional comments in the answer.

Comment: I was thinking about the order afterwards and it is probably why it was trapped in a endless loop. It is brilliant to use a reversed loop. Also I meant to copy D2 to E1. But I had to start the loop with 2 coz for whatever reasons, python counts the header row as row #1. Will have to manually fix the header row. Should the loop be (2,mr+1,2)?

Comment: Sorry its not clear to me how you want the copying to work now. As far as I see from your example D2 is a Street Address, not sure why it would be copied to row 1. THen how the rest of the rows are to be handled. Either way you shouldn't have to manually fix the header row but too confused now as to what your expected end result should be to comment on the loop action.